# The command line is too long(windows)

Tags: cmd, netsh

When i run "netsh advfirewall  firewall  set  rule  name= aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa  dir= in  protocol= tcp   localport= 8899 new remoteip=" with 5000 ips,it will be error,how should i do?

Answer (score 1):

A command has a max limit of 250 characters

You can get around this by using a codeblock instead

```
C:\Users\Steve> (
    netsh advfirewall firewall set rule
    name= aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
    dir= in
    ...
)
```

Comment: by codeblock you mean brackets at each end don't you ? Because that didin't work either